# How Can I change Html.PasswordFor to Html.TextboxFor when click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When I click the `span` tag I want to change `Html.PasswordFor()` to `Html.TextboxFor()` when I click in Javascript or jQuery. How Can I do this? I know this in input field but I don't know in Html Helpers.

```
@Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Parola, new 
{ 
  placeholder = "Password *", 
  @class = "form-control p-4 font-weight-bold mb-4", 
  style = "position:relative;", 
  required = "required" 
})
                                
<span style="position:absolute;right:20px;top:192px;">
  <i class="fas fa-eye fa-1x"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: You can't use the Html helpers. They only exist server side and browser knows nothing about them

Comment: Why not generate both and hide 1 initially, then toggle visibility (or whatever extra operation) when user clicks `span` tag?

Comment: Add both, look at the rendered HTML, then remove one and use jquery to change the one that's left so it looks like the one that was removed.   `@Html.xxFor` isn't "magic", it's a "helper" to generate html (and in most cases just confuses things hence helper in quotes)

Comment: @SangSuantak normally, I'd agree with you, but in this case it looks like OP is looking for one of those "see what your password is when clicking the eye" inputs that are becoming popular (and very helpful), so you'd have to also copy the value across (which is probably easier anyway...)

Comment: @freedomn-m if that's the case, i would suggest an overlay text/label which will contain the typed password value. This label will have the same positioning (css) as the password input box and its visibility could be toggled based on the span click.
If i'm not wrong, there's also a JS library for this which would make it a much more elegant/reusable solution.

Answer (score 1):

> When I click the span tag I want to change `Html.PasswordFor()` to `Html.TextboxFor()` when I click in Javascript or jQuery. How Can I do this?

As @charlietfl and @freedomn-m mentioned in comment,  such `Html.PasswordFor()` and `Html.TextboxFor()` etc HTML Helpers (or other Tag Helpers) enable web developers to create and render HTML elements in C# code at server-side. The JavaScript or jQuery code is executed on browser client-side, therefore you can not directly change these server-side HTML Helpers code on JS client side.

Besides, if you'd like to dynamically switch password input to regular text input from client side, you can try:

*html code snippet*

```
<span id="btnpwdmode" style="position:absolute;right:20px;top:192px;">
    <i class="fa fa-eye fa-1x"></i>
</span>
```

*jQuery code snippet*

```
$("#btnpwdmode").click(function () {
    var pwd_input_mode = $("#ID").attr("type");

    if (pwd_input_mode == "password") {
        $("#ID").attr("type", "text");
    } else {
        $("#ID").attr("type", "password");
    }
})
```

For more information about HTML Helpers and Tag Helpers, you can check this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0#tag-helpers-compared-to-html-helpers